# When I lock Ubuntu Random apps are being opened

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

I have dual booted Ubuntu on my hp laptop alongside windows 10. Whenever I shut the lid or manually lock the OS and unlock after a long time I see lots of opened windows. Is it a virus or something?

**Edit**:There are no apparent patterns to the programs being opened.

Sometimes they are additional browser windows and sometimes the trash and random folders and sometimes the application store also.

Also it happens every time I close the lid or lock Ubuntu and it stays idle for more than 5 minutes.

Comment: What kind of windows? Messages? Console windows? Applications you've previously opened?

Comment: just to be sure, does the same problem occur on startup?? Have you noticed any pattern among the programs that are being opened,  e.g. their location??

Comment: @OriolGonzalo no it does not occur at startup only when i use the lock system feature on ubuntu or when i close the lid and leave it idle for a long time